# Energy and wavefunction for modified potential well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, potential, schroedinger-equation

[image]

As depicted in the picture, the blue curve represents the potential. I want to find out the wavefunction for the 3 regions i.e. $x<0,0<x<a,x>a$

Is there any general way to draw the ground state wavefunction for these 3 regions if the energy of the incoming particle from left side $E<V_0$? Actually if this question is asked in an interview, I won’t get the time to solve Schrodinger equation and the constants by applying the boundary conditions.

If 1000 particles are coming and the energy of the incident particles is 5 eV and $V_0=10$ eV, how many particles will be found in the region $x>a$ , $a=10 nm$ ?

Comment: see https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/physics/ntg/H133/handouts/wavefunctions.pdf for a set of rules to qualitatively draw wavefunctions for arbitrary potentials.  In fact your question is done almost verbatim in those notes.

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy. Can you tell me anything about the last part?

Comment: You’d need to do a computation for this.  Do you just need an estimate?  You solution will be $0$ at the origin, and in the linear part the solution is a Airy function (see   https://www.classe.cornell.edu/~dlr/teaching/p443/LinearPotential.pdf ). It might be possible to compute 1-P(x<a) but it doesn’t look so easy.  Maybe you can use the fact that V=E is an inflexion point… not sure…

Comment: Okay. I got your point. Thanks again.